# Scale Y-Axis of a Chart depending on the Values within a section of X-Values for several Series

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, axis, scaling

I have got an aplication like this:
[image: Chart with scaling for the X-axis]
With the textboxes below the chart the user can set the min and max of the X-Axis of the Chart. This is the code for it:

```
private void textBoxXaxisMin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double x;
    //checks if the input is a double and smaller than the max value
    //if (Double.TryParse(this.textBoxXaxisMin.Text, out x) && x < chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum)    
    if (Double.TryParse(this.textBoxXaxisMin.Text, out x))
    {
        this.textBoxXaxisMin.BackColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(this.textBoxXaxisMin.Text);
        //changeYScalaMin(chartCharacteristicCurvesThermoelemts, Convert.ToDouble(this.textBoxCharacteristicCurvesThermoelementXmin.Text), Convert.ToDouble(this.textBoxCharacteristicCurvesThermoelementXmax.Text));     

        //method to scale y axis

    }
    else
        //if the textbox is not highlighted 
        this.textBoxXaxisMin.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    //calls the Max Function to update the chart if the Max-value is now valid

    double y;
    //checks if the input is a double and greater than the min value
    if (Double.TryParse(this.textBoxXaxisMax.Text, out y) && y > chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum)
    {
        this.textBoxXaxisMax.BackColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Convert.ToDouble(this.textBoxXaxisMax.Text);


        //method to scale y axis

    }
    else
        //if the textbox is not  highlighted 
        this.textBoxXaxisMax.BackColor = Color.Orange;
}
```

Now I would like to have the Y-axis scaled automatically. Y-min should be calulated as the min value of all series in the section of (X-min and X-max) and the Y-max as the maximum of all series in the selected section. My problem is the implementation.

In this example, Y-min should be changed to about 50.

I hosted the hole exampleproject here at [GitHup](https://github.com/kimliv/AxisScaling).

Comment: So what problem are you having? "Me problem lies on the implementation" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: @ChrisRyding how to find for example the Y-minimum value of all series in the given section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will scale the Y-Axis to the Minimum and Maximum values between the  Minimum and Maximum values[0] of the X-Axis for all series from 0 to 1:

```
double max = Double.MinValue; 
double min = Double.MaxValue; 

double leftLimit  = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
double rightLimit = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;

for (int s = 0; s <= 1; s++)
{
    foreach (DataPoint dp in chart1.Series[s].Points)
    {
        if (dp.XValue >= leftLimit && dp.XValue <= rightLimit)
        {
            min = Math.Min(min, dp.YValues[0]);
            max = Math.Max(max, dp.YValues[0]);
        }
    }
}

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = max;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = min;
```

Edit: While testing I noticed that resetting the Min&Max Values is not quite obvious. Here is how:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = Double.NaN;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Double.NaN;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Double.NaN;
```

Answer (score 8):

The axis minimum is automatically sets to 0, just use the IsStartesFromZero property:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
```

Comment: I was searching for automatic scaling of y-axis. and this is the perfect solution! Brilliant

Answer (score 4):

The code I used for my project is: (based on @TaW's answer)

```
private void changeYScala(object chart)
{
    double max = Double.MinValue;
    double min = Double.MaxValue;

    Chart tmpChart = (Chart)chart;

    double leftLimit = tmpChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
    double rightLimit = tmpChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;

    for (int s = 0; s < tmpChart.Series.Count(); s++)
    {
        foreach (DataPoint dp in tmpChart.Series[s].Points)
        {
            if (dp.XValue >= leftLimit && dp.XValue <= rightLimit)
            {
                min = Math.Min(min, dp.YValues[0]);
                max = Math.Max(max, dp.YValues[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    //tmpChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = max;
    tmpChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = (Math.Ceiling((max / 10)) * 10);
    tmpChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = (Math.Floor((min / 10)) * 10);
    //tmpChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = min;
}
```

This method is called in the question code above with:

```
changeYScala(chart1);
```

don't forget to include:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

Comment: looks ok. I like the Floor and Ceiling idea! +1

Comment: On second thought I still __like__ the idea but want to put in a word of __warning__: The way to add a little to the range entirely __depends on the actual numbers__. For your large integers it works fine, but my test case was using a `sin` and `cosine` plot and would have needed quite different numbers or an entirely different formula to accomplish the task of expanding the value range a 'bit'.